# Where can I get design details about spacecrafts and space mission?

Tags: mission-design, historical-data

I am doing a project on designing a mission to Mars. I am researching similar missions and I want to find information on the mission details like Delta V, trajectories etc. and details of the spacecraft like budget, dimensions, mass of subsystems, power used by subsystems etc. I have gone through press kits for many of the missions, Wikipedia, mission pages in NASA. Although they have given me a lot of information they fail to give all details I need and sometimes two sources give conflicting details. I tried The NASA technical report server, but it gives lots of information on things I do not need.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Space Stack Exchange!  The problem you are facing is quite common. Its worth pursuing but hard to respond to given the way your question is written a) because the topics are vast and b) because this is specifically a question and answer site.   I suggest that you try and break the problem down into chunks that have a more manageable and specific question and raise each of these as separate questions. Where you've said "they fail to give all details I need and sometimes two sources give conflicting details." is a good place to focus, i.e. what do you need and what are the conflicts?

Comment: ...in the mean time you could try spaceflight101.com!